# Trace32 config file error

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am using following settings to control trace32 cmm scripts execution using C# scripts.
    `Node="localhost"
    Port="20000"
    PackLen="1024"
    Device="1"`

Somehow I recently uninstalled & installed trace32 & lost config file. Now I am not able to execute T32_Init() function itself. Can someone give me the config file content ?

Answer (score 2):

If TRACE32 still starts, but you just can't connect to it via the remote API, add the following lines to your TRACE32 configuration file (config.t32):

```
RCL=NETASSIST
PORT=20000
```

There must be an empty line before and after that block.